# Macbook superdrive got calibration problems

Tags: macbook, burning

On intel macbook dual 2Ghz with Matshita DVD-R UJ 857 drive

Trying to burn DVD with toast titanium or Mac Book's built-in software will throw:

```
medium error, sense code = 0x73, 0x03
peripheral couldn't calibrate power of the laser required for medium
```

Some DVDs will actually work, but others won't.

What calibration means do I have to be able to burn on unrecognized media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error, it turned out that I had a defective drive and managed to get it replaced by Apple. I have also heard stories of people using compressed air to clear dust from their drives; with mixed results.

Hope this helps.

Ross